# Adaptive Pole Placement and Canonical forms

Tags: control-theory, canonical-transformation

I have a linear system in the observable canonical form as 
\begin{align}
  \dot{x} &= \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  -a_2 & 1&0\\
  -a_1 & 0&1\\
  -a_0 & 0&0
  \end{pmatrix}}_{A}x + \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  b_2\\b_1\\1
  \end{pmatrix}}_{B}u\\
  y&=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  1&0&0
  \end{pmatrix}}_{C}x
 \end{align}
    where $b_2,b_1>0$. Assuming $x$ is available for measurement, i would like to design a state-space adaptive pole placement controller so that the closed loop poles are all located at $c$, and hence $x$ and $y$ converge to zero.

As a first step, i designed a PPC as if the parameters were known. The question is: do I need to convert the system into the controllable canonical form? Doing this I would obtain 
\begin{align}
  \dot{x} &= \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  -a_0 & -a_1 & -a_2
  \end{pmatrix}}_{A_c} x + \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  0\\0\\1
  \end{pmatrix}}_{B_c}u\\
  y &= \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  1&b_1&b_2
  \end{pmatrix}}_{C_c}x
  \end{align}

which makes the estimation of the unknown parameters more tricky as $b_2, b_1$ are disappearing from the B matrix. Indeed, considering this canonical form, I'm not sure if the we can structure a Static parameter model like $z(t)= \theta_p^{*,T}\phi(t)$ with
        \begin{equation}
   z = \frac{s^3}{\varLambda_p(s)}x, \quad \theta_p^{*,T}=\begin{pmatrix}
   \theta_b^*\\\theta_a^*
   \end{pmatrix}, \quad \phi= \begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{\alpha_2(s)}{\varLambda_p(s)}u\\-\frac{\alpha_2(s)}{\varLambda_p(s)}x
   \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation} 
        where $\varLambda_p(s)$ is a stable monic polynomial. An other possible way to estimate the parameters could be considering the transfer function
\begin{equation}\label{tf5}
   G(s)=\frac{ b_2 s^2 + b_1 s+1}{s^3+ a_2 s^2  + a_1 s + a_0}
  \end{equation}
and then building a SPM from that, but I'm not sure about this. Any insights?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with PPC and SPM?

Comment: PPC is pole placement control and SPM is static parameter model